# What screen filters to use for 480 x 320 and smaller

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I want to publish two .apks of my application on the android market so I can support a smaller apk for older devices. I understood that I have to use different filters in my AndroidManifest file. I have two versions of my program, one for screens 480 x 320 and smaller (320 x 240), and one for any other screen bigger than 480 x 320. But I'm a little confused, what's the best filter to use: screen density or screen size. And what is the size of 480 x 320? Maybe android:normalScreens, but I'm not quite sure.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm a little confused, what's the best filter to use: screen
>   density or screen size

If you have resources for all the screen densities in their respective folders, you don't need to set the density filter, size filter will do.

> And what is the size of 480 x 320? Maybe android:normalScreens, but
>   I'm not quite sure

Yes.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screens-table) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the layout-small folder is for 320*240 screens.

Also, you can try another folder : layout-small-notlong-ldpi.

Regards